# How to write relationship of b and c

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Hi I am doing a research which involves matrices, and I wish to find the relation between $b$ and $c$. The nxn matrix is given as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  ... & 0 \\
   0 & 1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 & 0 &   ... & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 &  ... & 0 \\
   ...\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1/2  & -c \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1/2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
   b_{1}   \\
   b_{2}  \\
   b_{3} \\
   ...\\
   b_{N-2} \\
   b_{N-1} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{1}   \\
   a_{2}  \\
   a_{3} \\
   ...\\
   a_{N-1} \\
   a_{N} \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

It is crucial for me to find the relation between $b$ and $c$. Can someone help me drop some hints on how I can achieve that. Sorry the matrix is not well written. It is suppose to be in the form of $A\tilde{b}=\tilde{a}$.

Comment: Should your matrix be \begin{bmatrix}
   1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  ... & 0 \\
   0 & 1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 & 0 &   ... & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1/2  & -c & 1/2 & 0 &  ... & 0 \\
   ...\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0& 1/2  & -c \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1/2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believing Lord Shark's version, you can just do back substitution, starting at the bottom.  You get 
$$\frac 12b_N=a_N\\b_N=2a_N\\\frac 12b_{N-1}-cb_N=a_{N-1}\\b_{N-1}=2a_{N-1}+2cb_N\\
\frac 12b_{N-2}-cb_{N-1}+\frac 12b_N=a_{N-2}\\
b_{N-2}=2(a_{N-2}+cb_{N-1})-b_N$$
and so on up the line

Comment: But how does this helps me get the relation between b and c, because I still have all the a_N terms in there.

Comment: It has to depend on the $a$'s.  They are part of the equation.  If all the $a$s are zero, so are all the $b$'s regardless of $c$.